# How to use writeFile and readFile together in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

In the code below, `content1` becomes `undefined`. I want it to equal `11111`

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('./1.txt','11111',function(err,data{
  var content1 = fs.readFile('./1.txt',function(err,data){
    console.log(content1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback) do not have a return value.

The contents of the read file will be in the parameter `data` of the callback function. You should also include the encoding in the options param so you can write/print the contents as text.

```
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('./1.txt','11111','utf8',function(err,data){
  fs.readFile('./1.txt','uft8',function(err, content1){
    console.log(content1);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things are actually missing in your code:

1- `writeFile` and `readFile` functions are both asynchronous the result is only accessible by a callback function or a promise if it is handled, so in the code below we are accessing the result using callback function.

2- Consider using 2 different names for the callback result from `writeFile` and readFile as you are using `data` in both of them.

try this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('./1.txt', '11111', function(err, writeData) {
    fs.readFile('./1.txt',  "utf8", function(err, readData) {
        console.log(readData);
    });
});
```

Comment: Answers with no explanation at all are never as good as answers that include some text explaining what was wrong with the original code.

Comment: you are right edited with my understanding to the issue